# Problems with folder permissions in xampp with mac

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp-vm

I've got a problem with my mac, I've installed the last version of xampp server (7.2.7-0) in it.

The problem is that my mac doesn't allow me to read and write in the folder of data from mysql folder.

Even, it doesn't allow me through the terminal, saying "access dinied".

the problem is that just the sistem have the necesary perssions to read and write but not me (the administrator).

My OSX is macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Someone out there knows how to override this behavior from OSX?